# why this exception occurs please help me

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;

class Iostream5{ 

  public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{

     FileOutputStream f1=new FileOutputStream("ajay.txt");

     String aa="hello ajay its very bad that u given all information";    
     byte Fileinfo[]=aa.getBytes(aa);

     f1.write(Fileinfo);
     f1.close();   
     System.out.println("Sucesss...");

    }
}
```

**Exception Trace**

Exception in thread "main"

```
java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: hello ajay its very bad that u given 
all information
    at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:341)
    at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:916)
    at Iostream5.main(Iostream5.java:6)
```

Comment: Try `byte Fileinfo[]=aa.getBytes();` intead of `byte Fileinfo[]=aa.getBytes(aa);`.

Comment: Variable names should start with lower-case letter
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Answer (score 3):

Error is in the line

> byte Fileinfo[]=aa.getBytes(aa);

The parameter you pass is supposed to be the charset encoding (e.g. "UTF-8"). As the String aa is not a valid encoding itself, you get an UnsupportedEncodingException.

You can read about it in the Java docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is no method with the signature `String.getBytes(String)` which is what you are using. Instead use `aa.getBytes()` or change the signature to `Charset` which is the other alternative as you can see in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset)).

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned above you could change this line of code:

```
byte Fileinfo[]=aa.getBytes(aa);
```

by

```
byte Fileinfo[]=aa.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

or

```
byte Fileinfo[]=aa.getBytes(Charset.forName("Windows-1252"));
```

Depending on the encoding you are targeting

Answer (score 0):

Check the javaDoc for the method you are using.

> getBytes(String charsetName)
>   Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the named charset, storing the result into a new byte array.

Argument should hold a valid charsetName, Not the string to be converted in to Bytes.